# Packages for turtelbot2

Tags: ros, navigation, packages, turtlebot2, turtlebot-navigation

i am new to ROS world and i have to find ROS1 and ROS2 packages for turtelbot2 and compare them (what changed from ROS1 to ROS2), what are those Packages and where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is [this one](https://github.com/ros2/turtlebot2_demo).
Notice that we are now using [turtlebot3](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3), that's why the repo for turtlebot2 is archived

Answer (score 0):

Turtlebot2 is no longer officially supported on ROS2 (https://github.com/ros2/turtlebot2_demo is archived), but there are a handful of repos on github that allow it to run in Humble and Iron [[1](https://github.com/ingotrobotics/turtlebot2_ros2), [2](https://github.com/igrak34/turtlebot2-ros2)]. There have been quite a few changes to ROS2 and the Kobuki base drivers since Bouncy, so I would not use the archived repo as a reference for how to do things in ROS2.